# Format HTML with treewalker

Tags: javascript

I am unable to get this code to work fully. I have noticed that when one highlights a text from bottom to top as opposed from top to bottom the results are different.

I have been able to somewhat get it to work when I hightlight from bottom to top (i.e. start highlighting in the middle of line four to line 2 so you have 2.5 lines highlighted)

[image]

My goal is to enable my editor to format the highlighted text whether it is bold, underscored, color, and so on.

Below is the HTML in an editable div:

```
<div contenteditable="false" parentdiv="container" id="someID"  style="z-index: 50; width: 207px; height: 124px; top: 285px; left: 151.99px; position: absolute; outline-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" placeholder="double click to type">
    <div class="divContent" contenteditable="false" placeholder="Type here" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); cursor: move; z-index: 2; outline-color: rgb(170, 170, 170); opacity: 1; border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);" haserror="1">
        <span class="fontFormatContainer" style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 12pt; line-height: 1.3;">First line of text</span><br>
        <span class="fontFormatContainer" style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 8pt; line-height: 1.3;">Developer</span><br>
        <span class="fontFormatContainer" style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 1.3;">Cell: (941) 405-8180</span><br>
        <span class="fontFormatContainer" style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 1.3;">Cell: (941) 405-1111</span><br>
        <span class="fontFormatContainer" style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 1.3;">Another line of text</span><br>
        <span class="fontFormatContainer" style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 1.3;">https://Some.URL.com/Registration.asp</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my code:

```
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  if (!selection.isCollapsed) { // we have a non-zero length selection
    var endNode = selection.focusNode;
    var endOffset = selection.focusOffset;
    if (endNode instanceof Text) { // if an element then offset = child node idx
      endNode.splitText(endOffset);
    }

    var startNode = selection.anchorNode;
    var startOffset = selection.anchorOffset;
    if (startNode instanceof Text) {
      startNode.splitText(startOffset);
      startNode = startNode.nextSibling;
    }
 }

 function filterFunction(node) {
   if (node.id === 'ignore')
     return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
   return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
 }

 var nodeTypes = NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT | NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT;
 var root = range.commonAncestorContainer;
 var walker = document.createTreeWalker(root, nodeTypes, { acceptNode: filterFunction }, false);
 walker.currentNode = startNode;

 var nextNode = walker.currentNode;
 //var html = [];

 if (startOffset < endOffset) {
   while (nextNode && nextNode !== endNode) {
     if (nextNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
       if (nextNode.nodeValue.trim() !== '') {
         switch (objStyle.val) {
           case 'bold':
             $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr).indexOf('700') !== -1 ? objStyle.val = 'normal' : objStyle.val = '700';
             break;
           case 'italic':
             $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr).indexOf('italic') !== -1 ? objStyle.val = 'normal' : objStyle.val = objStyle.val;
             break;
          case 'underline':
             $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr).indexOf('underline') !== -1 ? objStyle.val = 'none' : objStyle.val = objStyle.val;
             break;
          case 'line-through':
             $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr).indexOf('line-through') !== -1 ? objStyle.val = 'none' : objStyle.val = objStyle.val;
             break;
         }

         if (nextNode.nodeValue === nextNode.parentElement.innerText)
            $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr, objStyle.val);
         else {
            var baseHTML = nextNode.parentElement.innerHTML;
            baseHTML = baseHTML.replace(nextNode.nodeValue, '<span style="' + objStyle.attr + ':' + objStyle.val + '">' + nextNode.nodeValue + '</span>');
            nextNode.parentElement.innerHTML = baseHTML; //nextNode.parentElement.innerHTML.replace(html[i], '');
         }
      }
   }
   nextNode = walker.nextNode();
 }
} else {
    while (nextNode && nextNode !== endNode) {
      if (nextNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        if (nextNode.nodeValue.trim() !== '') {
          switch (objStyle.val) {
            case 'bold':
              $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr).indexOf('700') !== -1 ? objStyle.val = 'normal' : objStyle.val = '700';
              break;
            case 'italic':
              $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr).indexOf('italic') !== -1 ? objStyle.val = 'normal' : objStyle.val = objStyle.val;
              break;
            case 'underline':
              $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr).indexOf('underline') !== -1 ? objStyle.val = 'none' : objStyle.val = objStyle.val;
              break;
            case 'line-through':
              $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr).indexOf('line-through') !== -1 ? objStyle.val = 'none' : objStyle.val = objStyle.val;
              break;
        }

   if (nextNode.nodeValue === nextNode.parentElement.innerText)
      $(nextNode.parentElement).css(objStyle.attr, objStyle.val);
   else {
      var baseHTML = nextNode.parentElement.innerHTML;
      baseHTML = baseHTML.replace(nextNode.nodeValue, '<span style="' + objStyle.attr + ':' + objStyle.val + '">' + nextNode.nodeValue + '</span>');
      nextNode.parentElement.innerHTML = baseHTML;                                         
      }
    }
  }
  nextNode = walker.previousNode();
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example HTML as well? Maybe you could add a snippet

Comment: Jorjon, thank you for your response.  I shall try to edit the code above with the HTML.

Comment: You could try to achieve a similar result using the CSS [::selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) pseudoclass

Comment: Ward, thank you for the response.  I am, however, not familiar with that class.  Can you please provide an example.  Maybe something like if I wanted to bold selected text.  I do need the change to be applied to the text though and not be undone when another text is selected.  Thank you